# Is there a Java equivalent of the Python sched module?

Tags: java, python, function, scheduling

Raymond Hettinger has posted a [snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413137-call-a-functionmethod-x-times-per-second/#c3) where he uses the sched module available in the standard Python library in order to call functions with a specific rate (N times per second). I wonder if there is an equivalent library in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at java.util.Timer.

You can find an example of use [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm)

You can also consider Quartz, which is much more powerful and can be used in combination
with Spring
Here is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/)

Here is my equivalent using java.util.Timer of the code snippet you mentionned

```
package perso.tests.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerExample  extends TimerTask{

      Timer timer;
      int executionsPerSecond;

      public TimerExample(int executionsPerSecond){
          this.executionsPerSecond = executionsPerSecond;
        timer = new Timer();
        long period = 1000/executionsPerSecond;
        timer.schedule(this, 200, period);
      }

      public void functionToRepeat(){
          System.out.println(executionsPerSecond);
      }
        public void run() {
          functionToRepeat();
        }   
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("About to schedule task.");
        new TimerExample(3);
        new TimerExample(6);
        new TimerExample(9);
        System.out.println("Tasks scheduled.");
      }
}
```

Comment: Both the Timer class and the Quartz library are offering a cron-like interface, scheduling jobs at specific times or taking place every N time units. What I need is a scheduler that schedules tasks to achieve a specific rate, e.g. N function (method) calls per time unit. Just like in the snippet I posted @Tichodroma

Comment: @dkart,as you can see in my answer, it is quite easy to create an application having the behaviour you expect...unless I have missed something

Comment: You're welcome @dkart! Please, do not forget to mark the response you that answered to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at http://quartz-scheduler.org/

> Quartz is a full-featured, open source job scheduling service that can be integrated with, or used along side virtually any Java EE or Java SE application - from the smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system.

Answer (score 2):

A light weight option is the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

The roughly equivalent Java code to the python snippet would be:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public ScheduledFuture<?> newTimedCall(int callsPerSecond, 
    Callback<T> callback, T argument) {
    int period = (1000 / callsPerSecond);
    return 
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                callback.on(argument);
            }
        }, 0, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Exercises left to the reader:

- Define the Callback interface
- Decide what to do with the returned future
- Remember to shut the executor down

Comment: +1 Probably the best solution. Funny that the Java snippet isn't that much longer than the Python equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I did cunningly leave out some of the boilerplate : )

Answer (score 1):

How about `java.util.Timer`? See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614590/1171043).

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [java.util.Timer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)?

You can find the example code [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CertainAndRepeatTime.shtml)