# How to raise N events per second in Java?

Tags: java

how can I raise N events per second in Java?

Basically I have a test harness where a want to raise events/called a method N times per second.

Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Maybe, you can take a look about using Threads.

Comment: N events per second means that you must fire the event every 1/N s. Have a look at `Thread.sleep();`

Comment: It is better to not use Thread and Thread.sleep() for this. Timer fits exactly the requirement in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As chrylis answered, `Timer` class can suit you. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016796/is-there-a-java-equivalent-of-the-python-sched-module/9016900#9016900) an answer I wrote that could help you.

```
package perso.tests.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerExample  extends TimerTask{

      Timer timer;
      int executionsPerSecond;

      public TimerExample(int executionsPerSecond){
          this.executionsPerSecond = executionsPerSecond;
        timer = new Timer();
        long period = 1000/executionsPerSecond;
        timer.schedule(this, 200, period);
      }

      public void functionToRepeat(){
          System.out.println(executionsPerSecond);
      }
        public void run() {
          functionToRepeat();
        }   
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("About to schedule task.");
        new TimerExample(3);
        new TimerExample(6);
        new TimerExample(9);
        System.out.println("Tasks scheduled.");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).